# How can I show the post time in my tumblr blog?

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes, tumblr-html

I tried following this https://smallbusiness.chron.com/show-date-tumblr-44477.html

doing this

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="main">
        {block:Posts inlineMediaWidth="700" inlineNestedMediaWidth="700"}
        <article class="
        {block:Text}     {block:Date} {block:NewDayDate} {DayOfWeek}, {Month} {DayOfMonth}, {Year} {/block:NewDayDate} {/block:Date} text     {/block:Text}
        {block:Photoset} {block:Date} {block:NewDayDate} {DayOfWeek}, {Month} {DayOfMonth}, {Year} {/block:NewDayDate} {/block:Date} photoset {/block:Photoset}
        {block:Photo}    {block:Date} {block:NewDayDate} {DayOfWeek}, {Month} {DayOfMonth}, {Year} {/block:NewDayDate} {/block:Date} photo    {/block:Photo}
        {block:RebloggedFrom}reblogged {/block:RebloggedFrom}
        {block:Quote}quote {/block:Quote}
        {block:Link}link {/block:Link}
        {block:Chat}chat {/block:Chat}
        {block:Audio}audio {/block:Audio}
        {block:Video}video {/block:Video}
        {block:Answer}answer {/block:Answer}
        {block:Date}not-page post-{PostID}
        {block:Date} {MonthNumberWithZero} / {DayOfMonthWithZero} / {ShortYear} {/block:Date}
        {/block:Date} {block:PermalinkPage} active exposed{/block:PermalinkPage}" {block:Date}data-post-id="{PostID}"{/block:Date} {block:SupplyLogging}data-supply-logging='{positions}'{/block:SupplyLogging}>
<div class="post-wrapper clearfix">
```

But I still don't display dates.

Comment: Is there some css in your theme that is hiding that block? Can you post a link to your tumblr. If the {blocks} are rendered it should show the relevant data.

Comment: Also you are passing alot of blocks to the class attribute of your article element. Maybe that is not closed at the right point?

Answer (score 0):

That page I referenced was worthless

I followed instructions here: http://themesbyeris.tumblr.com/tutorial07

Did this

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="main">
        {block:Posts inlineMediaWidth="700" inlineNestedMediaWidth="700"}
        <article class="
        {block:Text}text {/block:Text}
        {block:Photoset}photoset {/block:Photoset}
        {block:Photo}photo    {/block:Photo}
        {block:RebloggedFrom}reblogged {/block:RebloggedFrom}
        {block:Quote}quote {/block:Quote}
        {block:Link}link {/block:Link}
        {block:Chat}chat {/block:Chat}
        {block:Audio}audio {/block:Audio}
        {block:Video}video {/block:Video}
        {block:Answer}answer {/block:Answer}
        {block:Date}not-page post-{PostID}
        {block:Date} {MonthNumberWithZero} / {DayOfMonthWithZero} / {ShortYear} {/block:Date}
        {/block:Date} {block:PermalinkPage} active exposed{/block:PermalinkPage}" {block:Date}data-post-id="{PostID}"{/block:Date} {block:SupplyLogging}data-supply-logging='{positions}'{/block:SupplyLogging}>
        <div class="post-wrapper clearfix">

            <header class="post-header">
                {block:LikesPage}
                    <a class="post-blog" href="{Permalink}"><img class="blog-avatar" src="{PostBlogPortraitURL-30}" data-blog-card-username="{PostBlogName}">{PostBlogName}</a>
                {/block:LikesPage}
                {block:RebloggedFrom}
                    <a class="reblog-link" href="{ReblogParentURL}" data-blog-card-username="{ReblogParentName}"><i class="reblog_sm"></i>{ReblogParentName}</a>
                {/block:RebloggedFrom}
            </header>

            <section class="post">
            <a href="{Permalink}">{DayOfWeek}, {Year}-{MonthNumberWithZero}-{DayOfMonthWithZero} {24HourwithZero}:{Minutes}</a>
```

and it worked just fine.